# How to block a visitor IPv6 using Nginx config file

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

The IP below placed so many fake orders that were declined by Stripe and I want to block them from visiting my website. The IP is: 2406:da18:7c3:fd00:9154:21c5:335e:fb3b

Will the rule below work if I place it in this format in the nginx configuration file to block this guest from visiting my website?

```
location / {
   deny 2406:da18:7c3:fd00:9154:21c5:335e:fb3b;
 }
```

If I have to use something different please let me know.

[image]